# Null Pointer Exception at iteration line in for loop

Tags: apex

I am getting a null pointer exception when I am iterating over a set of custom settings which I have initialised earlier. Should the exception be thrown if the set is empty but not null?
`Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c` is a custom setting. I am following [Trigger Pattern for Tidy, Streamlined, Bulkified Triggers](https://meltedwires.com/2013/06/05/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers-revisited/) by Tony Scott.

```
/*Trigger Handler for the Account SObject. This class implements the  
*ITrigger interface to help ensure the trigger code is bulkified and all in one place.*/
public class Outstanding_TriggerHandler implements ITrigger{   
Map<String,String> mapOfProdDivsAndGrp = new Map<String, String>();
Map<String, Set<Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c>> mapOfGroupAndSetting =  new Map<String, Set<Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c>>();
Map<String,Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c> mapOfNameAndSetting = Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c.getAll();

public Outstanding_TriggerHandler() {
}

public void bulkBefore() {
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        for(Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c opgi : mapOfNameAndSetting.Values()) {
            if(!mapOfProdDivsAndGrp.containsKey(opgi.Product_Divisions__c)) {
                mapOfProdDivsAndGrp.put(opgi.Product_Divisions__c, opgi.Group_Index__c);
            }   
            if(!mapOfGroupAndSetting.containsKey(opgi.Group_Index__c)) {
                mapOfGroupAndSetting.put(opgi.Group_Index__c, new Set<Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c>());
            }
            mapOfGroupAndSetting.get(opgi.Group_Index__c).add(opgi);
        }
    }
}

public void bulkAfter() {        
}

public void beforeInsert(SObject so) {
    Outstanding__c os = (Outstanding__c)so;
    String prodgrp;
    Set<Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c> setOfSettings = new Set<Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c>();
    if(os.Product_Division__c != NULL && os.Days_Due__c != NULL) {
        for(String proddivs: mapOfProdDivsAndGrp.keySet()) {
            if(proddivs.contains(os.Product_Division__c)) {
                prodgrp = mapOfProdDivsAndGrp.get(proddivs);
                os.Product_Group_Index__c = prodgrp;
            }    
        }
        try {
            setOfSettings = mapOfGroupAndSetting.get(prodgrp);
            for(Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c opgi : setOfSettings) {
                if(os.Days_Due__c <= opgi.Due_Days_Upper_Limit__c && os.Days_Due__c > opgi.Due_Days_Lower_Limit__c) {
                    if(opgi.Index_Type__c == 'Higher') {
                        os.Higher_Approval_Level_Index__c = opgi.Approval_Index__c;
                    }    
                    if(opgi.Index_Type__c == 'Lower') {
                        os.Lower_Approval_Level_Index__c = opgi.Approval_Index__c;
                    }    
                }
            }        
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ExceptionLogging.addException('Outstanding Trigger Handler', ee);
        }    
    } else {
        os.Higher_Approval_Level_Index__c = NULL;
        os.Lower_Approval_Level_Index__c = NULL;
    }
}

public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so) {
}

public void beforeDelete(SObject so) {    
}

public void afterInsert(SObject so ) {   
}

public void afterUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so) { 
}

public void afterDelete(SObject so) {
}

public void andFinally() {
    ExceptionLogging.saveException();                
}
}
```

The Exception I am getting at the line `for(Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c opgi : setOfSettings)`:
is below -

```
System.NullPointerException
Attempt to de-reference a null object           
Class.Outstanding_TriggerHandler.beforeInsert: line 56, column 1
```

But I resolved the issue when I put an if condition for all the code in the try block:

```
if(mapOfGroupAndSetting.containsKey(prodgrp))
```

So I guess this line may also be causing the issue:

```
setOfSettings = mapOfGroupAndSetting.get(prodgrp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I'd expect you to get a `NullPointerException` if the custom setting you've called "isEmpty".

**Note** that I'm taking you literally from a coding standpoint.

`isEmpty()` returns true where objects & variables are `null`, for an empty string (`''`), a list with zero elements, a set with zero elements, and when a map has zero key-value pairs. When a set, list or map `isEmpty()`, there's nothing to iterate on.

Comment: If you attempt to use `isEmpty()` on a null object or variable it will throw a DNR error. It only check if a NON NULL object or variable list, set, map contains no items - re this statement (isEmpty() returns true where objects & variables are null)

Comment: See this from [Apex Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm?search_text=isEmpty) which is where my answer came from. DNR? That acronym isn't registering with me at the moment. `IsEmpty` can be used 2 ways depending on context. `someVar.isEmpty()` and `isEmpty(someVar)`. Are you referring to the diff between the two?

Comment: Dereference Null Object. Dang autocorrect. and if you do `somevar.isEmpty()` it will throw that if the object is null. Not sure if that was the context you meant or not. The doc you linked says: "Returns true if the list has zero elements" not null. `isEmpty(someVar)` will work if null

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes you can use `listVar.isEmpty()` to test to see if there are zero elements & `isEmpty(listVar)` would test for null. Although I've always understood the latter's primary usage to be for testing strings. It's always aggravated me how unclear the documentation is on whether to enclose or append methods to variables in cases like this one.

Comment: You are correct `isEmpty(somevar)` is for strings. Docs do leave a lot on the table and require one to piece a lot of assumptions together.

Comment: An empty object would have a `null` or `empty` field during run time when it's accessed. Even though a custom setting doesn't have an Id field, the platform still treats it as a custom object. For that reason, I'd expect to see the NPE thrown when it attempts to enter that loop.

Comment: I am only speaking of this line in your answer (I did not read the question) "isEmpty() returns true where objects & variables are `null`" if you are talking about `somevar.isEmpty()` then it is incorrect as it would throw NPE. Just a bit confusing. Or I just need coffee......

Answer (score 1):

Empty collection references do not throw a `NullPointerException` when accessed in a `for` loop using iterators, the loop simply exits without any iteration.  On the other hand, `null` collection references do throw a `NullPointerException` when accessed in a `for` loop.  This behavior can be tested with the following:

```
Set<String> testSet = new Set<String>();
for(string i : testSet)
{
    System.debug('Iterated Empty');
}
System.debug('For Loop Executed on Empty');
testSet = null;
for(String i : testSet)
{
    System.debug('Iterated Null');
}
System.debug('For Loop Executed on Null');
```

In your particular case, I think your issue is that one of your custom settings has a null field somewhere, though I'm still trying to figure out where that causes your logic to try to retrieve a map key that does not exist (which returns `null`, which sets your `setOfSettings` variable to null before trying to iterate).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this -

```
try {
        setOfSettings = mapOfGroupAndSetting.get(prodgrp);
        for(Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c opgi : setOfSettings) {
            if(os.Days_Due__c <= opgi.Due_Days_Upper_Limit__c && os.Days_Due__c > opgi.Due_Days_Lower_Limit__c) {
                if(opgi.Index_Type__c == 'Higher') {
                    os.Higher_Approval_Level_Index__c = opgi.Approval_Index__c;
                }    
                if(opgi.Index_Type__c == 'Lower') {
                    os.Lower_Approval_Level_Index__c = opgi.Approval_Index__c;
                }    
            }
        }        
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ExceptionLogging.addException('Outstanding Trigger Handler', ee);
    }
```

Check if values are null or not as below -

```
if(mapOfGroupAndSetting.containsKey(prodgrp) && mapOfGroupAndSetting(prodgrp) != null && mapOfGroupAndSetting(prodgrp) != ''){
setOfSettings = mapOfGroupAndSetting.get(prodgrp);
for(Outstanding_Product_Group_Index_Mapping__c opgi : setOfSettings) {
    if(os.Days_Due__c <= opgi.Due_Days_Upper_Limit__c && os.Days_Due__c > opgi.Due_Days_Lower_Limit__c) {
        if(opgi.Index_Type__c == 'Higher') {
            os.Higher_Approval_Level_Index__c = opgi.Approval_Index__c;
        }    
        if(opgi.Index_Type__c == 'Lower') {
            os.Lower_Approval_Level_Index__c = opgi.Approval_Index__c;
        }    
    }
}
```

}